# extract elements from xml in PL/SQl

Tags: xml, oracle, plsql, xml-parsing, extract

Below is the response of SOAP service. How do i extact values in Pl/SQL.. I have listed some of the ways i have tried

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Body>
   <ShipmentTrackingResponse xmlns="http://ws.aramex.net/ShippingAPI/v1/">
    <Transaction xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
     <Reference1>001</Reference1>
     <Reference2 i:nil="true"/>
     <Reference3 i:nil="true"/>
     <Reference4 i:nil="true"/>
     <Reference5 i:nil="true"/>
    </Transaction>
    <Notifications xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>   
    <HasErrors>false</HasErrors>
    <TrackingResults xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
     <a:KeyValueOfstringArrayOfTrackingResultmFAkxlpY>
      <a:Key>4738079651</a:Key>
      <a:Value>
      <TrackingResult>
       <WaybillNumber>4738079651</WaybillNumber>
       <UpdateCode>SH247</UpdateCode>
       <UpdateDescription>Supporting Document Returned to Shipper</UpdateDescription>
       <UpdateDateTime>2013-07-15T19:29:00</UpdateDateTime> 
       <UpdateLocation>Mumbai,India</UpdateLocation>
       <Comments/>
       <ProblemCode/>
      </TrackingResult>

      <TrackingResult>
       <WaybillNumber>4738079651</WaybillNumber>
       <UpdateCode>SH369</UpdateCode>
       <UpdateDescription>SMS Sent to Consignee</UpdateDescription>
       <UpdateDateTime>2013-07-12T09:10:00</UpdateDateTime>   
       <UpdateLocation>Mumbai,India</UpdateLocation>
       <Comments/>
       <ProblemCode/>
      </TrackingResult>

      <TrackingResult>
       <WaybillNumber>4738079651</WaybillNumber>
       <UpdateCode>SH033</UpdateCode>
       <UpdateDescription>Attempted Delivery - Payment Declined by Customer</UpdateDescription>
       <UpdateDateTime>2013-07-11T17:20:00</UpdateDateTime>
       <UpdateLocation>Goa Branch-GOI,India</UpdateLocation>
       <Comments/>
       <ProblemCode>A18</ProblemCode>
      </TrackingResult>

      <TrackingResult>
       <WaybillNumber>4738079651</WaybillNumber>
       <UpdateCode>SH369</UpdateCode>
       <UpdateDescription>SMS Sent to Consignee</UpdateDescription>
       <UpdateDateTime>2013-07-11T10:36:00</UpdateDateTime>
       <UpdateLocation>Mumbai,India</UpdateLocation>
       <Comments/>
       <ProblemCode/>
      </TrackingResult>

      <TrackingResult>
       <WaybillNumber>4738079651</WaybillNumber>
       <UpdateCode>SH003</UpdateCode>
       <UpdateDescription>Out for Delivery</UpdateDescription>
       <UpdateDateTime>2013-07-11T10:19:00</UpdateDateTime>
       <UpdateLocation>Goa Branch-GOI,India</UpdateLocation>
       <Comments/>
       <ProblemCode/>
      </TrackingResult>

      <TrackingResult>
       <WaybillNumber>4738079651</WaybillNumber>
       <UpdateCode>SH203</UpdateCode>
       <UpdateDescription>Record Created</UpdateDescription>
       <UpdateDateTime>2013-07-05T00:39:00</UpdateDateTime>
       <UpdateLocation>Nehru Place Branch,India</UpdateLocation>
       <Comments/>
       <ProblemCode/>
      </TrackingResult>
    </a:Value>
   </a:KeyValueOfstringArrayOfTrackingResultmFAkxlpY>
  </TrackingResults>
<NonExistingWaybills xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" 
xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/></ShipmentTrackingResponse></s:Body>
</s: Envelope>
```

How do i extract values, am literally stuck have tried all ways.
some of the methods are as follows:

```
l_resp_xml := XMLType.createXML(l_clob_response);
SELECT EXTRACT(l_resp_xml, '//ShipmentTrackingResponse/TrackingResults',
 'xmlns="http://ws.aramex.net/ShippingAPI/v1/"') INTO l_resp_xml FROM dual;
```

and finally for extracting values: But of no use! **PLEASE HELP!!**

```
SELECT EXTRACTVALUE(l_resp_xml, 
'//TrackingResults/a:KeyValueOfstringArrayOfTrackingResultmFAkxlpY/a:Value/TrackingResult[1]/UpdateDescription', 'xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays"')INTO l_response_result FROM dual;
DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ( 'Result> l_response_clobExtract=' || l_response_result);
```

how to use the XmlTable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Jafar for your help. I did the following and it worked fine!! Its solved.........

`select x.UPDATEDESCRIPTION , x.UpdateDateTime into l_response_message, l_response_result
                from 
                (select XMLType.createxml(l_clob_response) xml from dual) t,
                xmltable(
                 xmlnamespaces (
                 'http://ws.aramex.net/ShippingAPI/v1/' as "e",
                 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays' as "a",
                 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' as "s",
                  default 'http://ws.aramex.net/ShippingAPI/v1/'
                 ),
                 's:Envelope/s:Body/ShipmentTrackingResponse/TrackingResults/a:KeyValueOfstringArrayOfTrackingResultmFAkxlpY/a:Value/TrackingResult[1]'
                 passing t.xml
                 columns
                 UpdateDescription varchar2(128) path 'UpdateDescription',
                 UpdateDateTime varchar2(128) path 'UpdateDateTime'
                ) x;
                dbms_output.put_line('The UpdateDescription =>' || l_response_message);
                dbms_output.put_line('The UpdateDateTime =>' || l_response_result);`

Comment: glad to help..if my post did answer your question please mark it as an answer to help others who would come here later on..thnx

Answer (score 2):

You need to go down/to a specific XML tag/node

```
 SELECT *
   FROM XMLTable('$dat//xmlpath' --the path to the node you want to start reading from
                   PASSING your_xml_node AS "dat"
                   COLUMNS
                       vcol NUMBER PATH 'col_path', --from your given node
                       ...etc
                    ) ;
```

For every XML value you want to read you need to add a column under `COLUMNS` and map it to its path in your given XML node

You can read more in [Oracle Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions228.htm)

---

---

**EDIT** I used the XML you listed in your OP and here is how you can do it (I didnt have access to your *http://ws.aramex.net/ShippingAPI/v1/* schema so instead I used a `*` to query any schema/namespace).

The most **important** thing when dealing with *XML* is the paths, the reason you werent getting any results is because you had something wrong somewhere in your path. It took me a while to learn this, so good luck :)

```
    SELECT *
      FROM XMLTABLE (
              xmlnamespaces (
                 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' AS "s",
                 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays' AS "a"),
              '$xd/s:Envelope/s:Body/*:ShipmentTrackingResponse/*:TrackingResults/a:KeyValueOfstringArrayOfTrackingResultmFAkxlpY'
              PASSING xmltype (
                         '<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Body>
   <ShipmentTrackingResponse xmlns="http://ws.aramex.net/ShippingAPI/v1/">
    <Transaction xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
     <Reference1>001</Reference1>
     <Reference2 i:nil="true"/>
     <Reference3 i:nil="true"/>
     <Reference4 i:nil="true"/>
     <Reference5 i:nil="true"/>
    </Transaction>
    <Notifications xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>   
    <HasErrors>false</HasErrors>
    <TrackingResults xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
     <a:KeyValueOfstringArrayOfTrackingResultmFAkxlpY>
      <a:Key>4738079651</a:Key>
      <a:Value>
      <TrackingResult>
       <WaybillNumber>4738079651</WaybillNumber>
       <UpdateCode>SH247</UpdateCode>
       <UpdateDescription>Supporting Document Returned to Shipper</UpdateDescription>
       <UpdateDateTime>2013-07-15T19:29:00</UpdateDateTime> 
       <UpdateLocation>Mumbai,India</UpdateLocation>
       <Comments/>
       <ProblemCode/>
      </TrackingResult>

      <TrackingResult>
       <WaybillNumber>4738079651</WaybillNumber>
       <UpdateCode>SH369</UpdateCode>
       <UpdateDescription>SMS Sent to Consignee</UpdateDescription>
       <UpdateDateTime>2013-07-12T09:10:00</UpdateDateTime>   
       <UpdateLocation>Mumbai,India</UpdateLocation>
       <Comments/>
       <ProblemCode/>
      </TrackingResult>

      <TrackingResult>
       <WaybillNumber>4738079651</WaybillNumber>
       <UpdateCode>SH033</UpdateCode>
       <UpdateDescription>Attempted Delivery - Payment Declined by Customer</UpdateDescription>
       <UpdateDateTime>2013-07-11T17:20:00</UpdateDateTime>
       <UpdateLocation>Goa Branch-GOI,India</UpdateLocation>
       <Comments/>
       <ProblemCode>A18</ProblemCode>
      </TrackingResult>

      <TrackingResult>
       <WaybillNumber>4738079651</WaybillNumber>
       <UpdateCode>SH369</UpdateCode>
       <UpdateDescription>SMS Sent to Consignee</UpdateDescription>
       <UpdateDateTime>2013-07-11T10:36:00</UpdateDateTime>
       <UpdateLocation>Mumbai,India</UpdateLocation>
       <Comments/>
       <ProblemCode/>
      </TrackingResult>

      <TrackingResult>
       <WaybillNumber>4738079651</WaybillNumber>
       <UpdateCode>SH003</UpdateCode>
       <UpdateDescription>Out for Delivery</UpdateDescription>
       <UpdateDateTime>2013-07-11T10:19:00</UpdateDateTime>
       <UpdateLocation>Goa Branch-GOI,India</UpdateLocation>
       <Comments/>
       <ProblemCode/>
      </TrackingResult>

      <TrackingResult>
       <WaybillNumber>4738079651</WaybillNumber>
       <UpdateCode>SH203</UpdateCode>
       <UpdateDescription>Record Created</UpdateDescription>
       <UpdateDateTime>2013-07-05T00:39:00</UpdateDateTime>
       <UpdateLocation>Nehru Place Branch,India</UpdateLocation>
       <Comments/>
       <ProblemCode/>
      </TrackingResult>
    </a:Value>
   </a:KeyValueOfstringArrayOfTrackingResultmFAkxlpY>
  </TrackingResults>
<NonExistingWaybills xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" 
xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/></ShipmentTrackingResponse></s:Body>
</s:Envelope>') AS "xd"
              COLUMNS key_col NUMBER PATH 'a:Key',
                      values_col XMLTYPE PATH 'a:Value') xx;
```

Comment: Thanks for help, but what about the default namespaces, there's where am stuck. Can you please give a example

Comment: I did the following: `SELECT EXTRACT(l_resp_xml, '//s:Envelope/s:Body/node()', l_NAMESPACE_SOAP) INTO l_resp_xml FROM dual;`

Comment: and then:`SELECT xx.UPDATEDESCRIPTION into l_response_message 
       from xmltable(xmlnamespaces('http://ws.aramex.net/ShippingAPI/v1/' AS "a",
                                    'http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays' AS "n"),
                 '/ShipmentTrackingResponse/a:TrackingResults/n:KeyValueOfstringArrayOfTrackingResultmFAkxlpY/n:Value/n:TrackingResult[1]' passing l_resp_xml
                 columns 
                 UPDATEDESCRIPTION VARCHAR2(128) path 'n:UpdateDescription[1]') xx;
       DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Result> Update Description='|| l_response_message);`

Comment: But unfortunately of no use!!

Comment: It says no data found!!

Comment: if it says no data found then the XML schema you provided isnt correct, or the paths are not right.

Comment: @coder please see my edited answer. I took your sample XML in your OP and wrote a query to extract the data from your XML.